# Taking monadic functions out of a monad

Tags: haskell, types, monads

Haskell has the function `join`, which "runs" a monadic action which is inside a monad:

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
join m = m >>= \f -> f
```

We can write a similar function for monadic functions with one argument:

```
join1 :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> (a -> m b)
join1 m arg1 = m >>= \f -> f arg1
```

And for two arguments:

```
join2 :: Monad m => m (a -> b -> m c) -> (a -> b -> m c)
join2 m arg1 arg2 = m >>= \f -> f arg1 arg2
```

Is it possible to write a general function `joinN`, that can handle monadic functions with N arguments?

Comment: What do you think the type of that function would be?

Comment: I don't know. At first glance this seems impossible to me. But writing variadic functions in Haskell also seemed impossible to me, until I saw how it can be done with some typeclass magic. Maybe this is possible too, using typeclasses, or one of the type system extensions. I can't tell, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: There are values `x` such that `join x` *and* `join1 x` *and* `join2 x` are all well-typed. If you have this `joinN` function and say `joinN x`, which of the joins will get selected and why?

Comment: Thank you for all your great answers! Reading them has really helped me to understand Haskell's type system better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this with a fair amount of ugliness if you really desire.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad (join, liftM)

class Joinable m z | z -> m where
  joins :: m z -> z

instance Monad m => Joinable m (m a) where
  joins = join

instance (Monad m, Joinable m z) => Joinable m (r -> z) where
  joins m r = joins (liftM ($ r) m)
```

But, as you can see this relies on some shaky typeclass magic (in particular, the unenviable `UndecidableInstances`). It is quite possibly better—if ugly looking—to write all of the instances `join1`...`join10` and export them directly. This is the pattern established in the `base` library as well.

Notably, inference won't work too well under this regime. For instance

```
λ> joins (return (\a b -> return (a + b))) 1 2
Overlapping instances for Joinable ((->) t0) (t0 -> t0 -> IO t0)
  arising from a use of ‘joins’
Matching instances:
  instance Monad m => Joinable m (m a)
    -- Defined at /Users/tel/tmp/ASD.hs:11:10
  instance (Monad m, Joinable m z) => Joinable m (r -> z)
    -- Defined at /Users/tel/tmp/ASD.hs:14:10
```

but if we give an explicit type to our argument

```
λ> let {q :: IO (Int -> Int -> IO Int); q = return (\a b -> return (a + b))}
```

then it can still work as we hope

```
λ> joins q 1 2
3
```

This arises because with typeclasses alone it becomes quite difficult to indicate whether you want to operate on the monad `m` in the final return type of the function chain or the monad `(->) r` that *is the function chain* itself.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. The slightly longer answer is you could probably define an infix operator.

Take a look at the implementation for `liftM`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#liftM

It defines up to liftM5. This is because it's not possible to define liftMN, just like your joinN isn't possible.

But we can take a lesson from Appicative `<$>` and `<*>` and define our own infix operator:

```
> let infixr 1 <~> ; x <~> f = fmap ($ x) f
> :t (<~>)
(<~>) :: Functor f => a -> f (a -> b) -> f b
> let foo x y = Just (x + y)
> let foobar = Just foo
> join $ 1 <~> 2 <~> foobar
Just 3
```

This is quite reminiscent of a common applicative pattern:

```
f <$> a1 <*> a2 .. <*> an
join $ a1 <~> a2 .. <~> an <~> f
```

Answer (score 1):

A single function for every possible `N`? Not really. Generalizing over functions with different numbers of arguments like this is difficult in Haskell, in part because "number of arguments" is not always well-defined. The following are all valid specializations of `id`'s type:

```
id :: a -> a
id :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
id :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
...
```

We'd need *some* way to get `N` at the type level, and then do a different thing depending on what `N` is.

Existing "variadic" functions like `printf` do this with typeclasses. They establish what `N` is by induction on `->`: they have a "base case" instance for a non-function type like `String` and a recursive instance for functions:

```
instance PrintfType String ...
instance (PrintfArg a, PrintfType r) => PrintfType (a -> r) ...
```

We can (after a lot of thinking :P) use the same approach here, with one caveat: our base case is a bit ugly. We want to start with the normal `join`, which produces a result of type `m a`; the problem is that to support *any* `m a`, we have to overlap with normal functions. This means that we need to enable a few scary extensions and that we might confuse the type inference system when we actually use our `joinN`. But, with the right type signatures in place, I believe it should work correctly.

First off, here's the helper class:

```
class Monad m => JoinN m ma where
  joinN :: m ma -> ma
```

`ma` will take the relevant function type like `a -> m b`, `a -> b -> m c` and so on. I couldn't figure out how to leave `m` out of the class definition, so right off the bat we need to enable `MultiParamTypeClasses`.

Next, our base case, which is just normal `join`:

```
instance Monad m => JoinN m (m a) where
  joinN = join
```

Finally, we have our recursive case. What we need to do is "peel off" an argument and then implement the function in terms of a smaller `joinN`. We do this with `ap`, which is `<*>` specialized to monads:

```
instance (Monad m, JoinN m ma) => JoinN m (b -> ma) where
  joinN m arg = joinN (m `ap` return arg)
```

We can read the `=>` in the instance as implication: if we know how to `joinN` an `ma`, we also know how to do a `b -> ma`.

This instance is slightly weird, so it requires `FlexibleInstances` to work. More troublingly, because our base case (`m (m a)`) is made up entirely of variables, it actually overlaps with a bunch of other reasonable types. To actually make this work we have to enable `OverlappingInstances` and `IncoherentInstances`, which are relatively tricky and bug-prone.

After a bit of cursory testing, it *seems* to work:

```
λ> let foo' = do getLine >>= \ x -> return $ \ a b c d -> putStrLn $ a ++ x ++ b ++ x ++ c ++ x ++ d
λ> let join4 m a b c d = m >>= \ f -> f a b c d
λ> join4 foo' "a" "b" "c" "d"

a  b  c  d
λ> joinN foo' "a" "b" "c" "d"

a  b  c  d
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, "works with `IncoherentInstances`" means "doesn't work", and "works with `OverlappingInstances`" means "might work sometimes, but shouldn't be relied on."

Comment: @dfeuer: It seems okay here if you just don't export the class so nobody else can add any instances. (Well, unless it's already broken for `(->) r`.)

Comment: This makes me wonder if a closed type family distinguishing functions from other things might help matters. In the event that such a thing works, it might be less shady, maybe.